# How to find the number of common characters in inputted strings

Tags: python, string, set

I want to take input and perform operation to find the number of common letters in inputs (strings).

Example input:

```
abcaa
bcbd
bgc
```

Output is 2 because b and c present in all.

I try to write code but I'm stuck here in the 4th line:

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(3):
    s1=input()
    #a=list(set(s1)&set(s2))
print(a)

'''
input:
3
abcaa
bcbd
bgc

output:
2
because  'b' and 'c' are present in all three
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input the number as many you want to compare:

```
as_many_inputs = 3
asked_inputs = [set(input("Enter the string you want\t")) for i in range(as_many_inputs)]
from functools import reduce
print("Number of common is:\t", len(reduce(set.intersection, asked_inputs)))
```

Here you can use inbuilt reduce() function to find the intersection. Also, the len() will return the number.

```
Enter the string you want   aah

Enter the string you want   aak

Enter the string you want   aal
Number of common is:    1
```

I did the test with 5 as well:

```
Enter the string you want   agh

Enter the string you want   agf

Enter the string you want   age

Enter the string you want   agt

Enter the string you want   agm
Number of common is:     2
```

Comment: but sir i want this in loop that is if 5 is give it take 5 input and perform operation on that

Comment: Please try the updated one, for as many inputs you want to enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
t = int(input("How many inputs there will be:\t"))  # take the number of inputs will be given

inputs = []     # empty list for inputs

a = []  # empty list for inputs as set of letters

# loop through the range of t (total number of inputs given at first)
for i in range(t):
    input_taken = input("Enter your input:\t")  # take the input
    inputs.append(input_taken)  # store input to the inputs list

# loop through inputs, make sets of letters for each item and store them in a
for i in inputs:
    a.append(set(i))

u = set.intersection(*a)    # find the common letter's set from all items of a and save it as a set(u)

print(len(u), u)    # print the length of u and u(different letters from each items of a)
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Rohitjojo09`, you can try like this.

**Note:** I am using variable `n` in place of your `t` and `s` in place of `s1` and mostly this makes sense.

> You can try this code online at https://rextester.com/ISE37337.

```
def get_count():
    n = int(input())

    for i in range(n):
        s = input().strip()

        if not i:
            l = list(set(s))
        else:
            i = 0
            while l and i < len(l) - 1:
                ch = l[i]
                if not ch in s:
                    l.remove(ch)
                else:
                    i += 1                       
    return len(l)

count = get_count()                    
print(count) # 2
```

Output:

```
3
abcaa
bcbd
bgc
```

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK IT OUT !!**

```
s=set()   #create empty set
c=1
num=int(input("Enter no of strings you want to enter: "))
for i in range(num):
    x= input("enter string: ")
    if c < 2:
        for j in x:
            s.add(j)   #adding elemnts of x in set
        c+=1
    else:
        s=s.intersection(x)    

print(s,len(s))
```